# Live vertical viewport tracking not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get the current `y position` in de `document` to change the ui at certain moments.
The code I use atm doesn't work and I don't get why.

```
const [verticalPosition, setVerticalPosition] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    setVerticalPosition(window.scrollY)
}, [window.scrollY])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(verticalPosition)
}, [verticalPosition])
```

I've searched for alternatives and found the most complex libraries to do something just that easy. So I would want to make it work this way. Could someone tell me how this could get working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an event listener to the `document.scroll` event like so:

```
const [verticalPosition, setVerticalPosition] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = ()=>{
        setVerticalPosition(window.scrollY);
    }
    document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    return ()=>document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll); // cleanup function runs when component is unmounted
}, []); // empty dependency array so it only runs on mount
```

### Pro tip

If you need this behavior in multiple components, this is trivial to abstract into a custom hook:

```
// hooks/useScrollY.js
const useScrollY = ()=>{
  const [verticalPosition, setVerticalPosition] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
      const onScroll = ()=>{
          setVerticalPosition(window.scrollY);
      }
      document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
      return ()=>document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }, []); 
  return verticalPosition;
}
export default useScrollY;

// how to use:
import useScrollY from "../hooks/useScrollY"

const MyComponent = ()=>{
  const scrollY = useScrollY();
  // do something with scrollY
  return (
    //...
  );
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm 
For now the hook is not needed but I keep the tip in mind. Thanks a lot!